# Keeping one counter updated for several parallel streams

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

Trying to maintain one (synchronized) counter to keep track of List.parallelStream.
Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Testing the use of AtomicInteger in List.parallelStream()
 */
public void UsingParallelStream() {

    /*Create the counter */
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

    /*Create and populate the list */
    List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int num = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        numList.add(num);
        num ++;
    }

    /*Test the consistency of the counter*/
     numList.parallelStream().forEach(number -> {
         atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
         executeTest(atomicInteger,numList);
     });

}

private void executeTest(AtomicInteger atomicInteger, List<Integer> l) {
    if (atomicInteger.intValue() % 100 == 0) {
        System.out.println(l.get(atomicInteger.intValue() - 1));
    }
}
```

Here are the results (as you can see the counter is not synchronized):
100
200
300
300
401
501
501
701
800
901
800
1000

Thanks and Brgs,
David.

Comment: Sorry, here is the full code:

Comment: it is still not the full code. where is `executeTest`

Comment: Missing code added.

Answer (score 1):

The operations in  `executeTest(atomicInteger,numList);` are not atomic.

```
if (atomicInteger.intValue() % 100 == 0) {
    System.out.println(l.get(atomicInteger.intValue() - 1));
}
```

When a thread found `atomicInteger.intValue() % 100 == 0` was true, and try to execute `System.out.println(l.get(atomicInteger.intValue() - 1));`, other threads might have updated the value.

How to solve it? Use a local variable:

```
numList.parallelStream().forEach(number -> {
    int local = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
    executeTest(local,numList);
});


private void executeTest(int  local, List<Integer> l) {
    if (local % 100 == 0) {
        System.out.println(l.get(local - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: and why is that matter? please elaborate

Comment: but if `getAndIncrement()` is atomic, doesn't it mean that all threads see the same value at all times?

Comment: I think I see an example:   thread got context switch right after the if statement. so after the thread is awaken by the JVM, the value may be different, is that a valid example?

Comment: Once I've passed the atomicInteger to the executeTest method then it is only seen localy and not incremented outside the method. 
see for example:

 private void executeTest(AtomicInteger counter, List<Integer> l) {
  if (counter.intValue() % 100 == 0) {
   System.out.println(l.get(counter.intValue() - 1));
  }
 }

Comment: The problem is the OP called `atomicInteger.intValue` twice. Here is an example, thread1 found `atomicInteger.intValue` is 100, and try to print it. At the same time, thread2 update `atomicInteger` to 101, so when thread1 retrieve the value again, it will get 101.

Comment: @David No, you are using `parallelStream`. Other threads can modify the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that each thread operates on a different value. This value can only be found once, and only by the return value of `getAndIncrement`. Every further read operation on the atomic integer may return a new value, which belongs to another thread.

```
numList.parallelStream().forEach(number -> {
        var value = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
        executeTest(value, numList);
});

private void executeTest(int value, List<Integer> l) {
    if (value % 100 == 0) {
        System.out.println(l.get(value - 1));
    }
}
```

When you increment first, and read it afterwards, multiple threads may use the same value. Atmomic means, each operation is atomic. It doesn't mean that multiple operations are atomic within the same thread.